# Child_process fork - intermittent onread error

Tags: node.js, child-process

I’m trying to create a caching server in node using child_process.fork.

The basic idea is that there’s a dispatching server that will spawn off forked “caching servers” based on the incoming URI. Once the caching servers are forked, the client sockets are sent to their appropriate forked caching server via the fork’s .send method.

```
cacheServers[this.key] = require('child_process').fork(‘CacheServer.js’,[this.key]);
```

... and then

```
cacheServers[subKey].send(“client”,clientSocket);
```

At times sending the client (and its socket) to a fork works fine, and at other times it throws an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'onread' of null
at ChildProcess.handleConversion.net.Socket.send (child_process.js:134:21)
at ChildProcess.target.send (child_process.js:439:52)
at Server.server.Subscribe(/home/devuser/CachingServer/CachingServer.js:104:23)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/devuser/CachingServer/CachingServer.js:145:10)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:345:11)
```

There seems to be no difference in the clients I’m sending to the fork.

Anyone out there have any clue at all?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has been fixed in v0.11.13 and v0.10.27?

[Issue #5469](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5469)
, [Fix](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/5e06ce4fb949ab9bd5a7105dc0e8d924fd911d0c)
, [Test](https://github.com/indutny/node/commit/273e75ae6deefdcf5dd6fe7c26798468407dfdb5)

Comment: I'm still seeing the issue on v0.11.13, but it may be fine on other versions.